# Use value from DataBinder.Eval to show an image

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, databinder

I am using a Repeater and DataBinder.Eval to get the values from a code behind:

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="f" data-inset="true">
         <li data-theme="c">
          <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Email")%> 
         </li>
        </ul>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

`Email` returns **true** or **false**. If the value is **true** i want to show `image_open.png` and if it the value of `Email` is **false** than `image_close.png`

Is there something like:

```
<% if (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Email").Equals("true"))%>
   <img src="image_open.png" />
<% else %>
   <img src="image_close.png" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of conditional operator:

```
<img src='<%# ((bool)Eval("Email")) ? "image_open.png" : "image_close.png" %>' />
```

Comment: Yes it works :) Email returns a string but it was easy to convert it to boolean `bool readYesno=true?Email.ToString()=="true":false` .Thank you